# Defined Function Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, undefined-function

I have this JS:

```
 document.getElementById("config2").addEventListener("click", function(){
   config3();
   console.log("In Function config.onclick()...");
 });
 
 function config3()
 {
   document.body.innerHTML+="<div style=\"opacity:0;\" class=\"popoutcont\" id=\"formcont\"><div style=\"opacity:0;\"><div class=\"popoutform\"></div></div>";
   setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("formcont").style.opacity+=0.01;if(document.getElementById("formcont").style.opacity===1){clearInterval(this)}}, 1);
   console.log("In Function Config...");
 }
```

And this HTML:

```
<p class='spectxt' style='font-weight:normal;' id='config2'><strong>Payload Configuration:</strong> Seats: 2</p>"
```

First of all, the event never occurs.  No output is sent to the console.
Second, the Chrome DevTools JS Console says that config3 is undefined when I call the function.
Why is this happening and what is causing it?

Comment: When you call what function? Where is the JS in relation to the HTML? Is it being run in a dom-ready mechanism? Details, please :)

Comment: In the console, when I call config3(), it reads "Uncaught ReferenceError: config3 is not defined."  The JS is in a script tag, and is the next element after the p tag.  It is not in an onready mechanism, when a user clicks on the p tag the function config3 should be called.

Comment: When you load the page are there any other errors that might prevent following JS from loading?

Comment: And there are no errors other than net::ERR_CACHE_MISS.

Comment: BAD BAD BAD design `document.body.innerHTML+="..."`

Comment: @epascarello How so?

Comment: I used ONLY the code that you have posted [I'm obviously missing the other elements like "formcont" etc], put the JS after the <p> element and I get this output with no errors:
In Function Config...
In Function config.onclick()...
Browser:Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 m
OS: Windows 7 32-bit

Comment: You override the content of the page which destroys the DOM each time. Learn about appendChild

Comment: @GVashhist That's weird.  I'm using chrome 39.0.2171.71 on Windows 8.

Comment: Create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or a snipplet here or a link to an actual page that shows the problem.

Comment: Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8gwutyp/).

Answer (score -1):

run your startup code on

```
<body onload="">
```

since your html content is not loaded yet